# what is this expression in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In javascript what is id && (js.id=id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same like

```
if (id) {       // test if id is truthy
    js.id = id; // assign id to js.id
}
```

Caveat: `id` can sometimes be `0`, so this value does not become assigned.

Comment: Thanks! Can't upvote your answers yet. Not used javascript for a while and find something like this on google does not give quick results like here..